# Exact arithmetic operations with fractions in R

Tags: r, math, symbolic-math, fractions

I want to implement (in R language) an algorithm which starts with vectors of integer numbers, and then proceed, step by step, to operate among them only with arithmetic operations (+, -, * and /).

I'm concerned about instability of division by small numbers, then I wish I could manage (within R types) with the exact fraction representation of all results. Then when I want to see the value of a vector, I would like to see the vector of exact fractions, results of all the performed operations.

I have been googling for in R documentation, packages, and I have found packages "FRACTION" and "fractional". They do something related, but not exact arithmetic: they seem to work with "real" numbers, do fix some tolerance, and then turn those truncated real numbers into their fractional representation.

Then I ask for help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Rmpfr package?

Comment: Thanks @joran for letting me know about the [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) package. Actually, I wish to "print" the fractional expression of the computed values at each step, on the console and in reports.